# Center logo in navbar list

Tags: html, css

CODEPEN: https://codepen.io/tylerisfatal/pen/vYgmaxJ

I have built a simple navbar with a list of icons and a logo inside the  element but outside the  element. This is sort of a two-part question:

1. How do I center this element? It's parent is the nav element, yet I can't seem to center it. I tried `margin: 0 auto` but it only centered it near the end of the flex container.
2. Is doing it this way (the logo inside the nav yet outside the ul) the most efficient way to write this?

HTML:

```
 <nav role="navigation" class="main-nav">
        <ul class="main-nav-list">
            <li class="fb">
                <a href="#facebook">
                    <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/capsocial-round/500/facebook-512.png" alt="">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#yelp">
                   <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-media-2169/24/social_media_social_media_logo_yelp-512.png" alt="">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#linkedin">
                    <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/linkedin_circle_color-512.png" alt="">
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
/* navbar Container */
.main-nav {
    display: flex;
    background-color: rgb(28, 143, 124);
    align-items: center;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}

/* ul Container*/
.main-nav 
.main-nav-list {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: auto; /* img placement */
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex-direction: row;
    list-style-type: none;
}

/* Responsive images */
.main-nav 
.main-nav-list li img {
    display: flex;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-height: 150px;
    max-width: 75px;
}

/* Logo */

.main-nav .logo {
  display: flex;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-height: 150px;
  max-width: 75px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply put a common wrapper div around your logo:

```
<div class="logo-wrapper">
    <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/icontober/64/Inkcontober_Deep_Dive_Suit-512.png" alt="" class="logo">
</div>
```

and position the logo with this css:

```
.logo-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 20%;
}
```

The logo wrapper gets 20% width, the ul container 40% width and both are per default flex-start-justified. So the logo wrapper is centered and also justifies its own content centered – so the logo itself is centerd.

**Working example** (click 'Full Page' to compare):

```css
.main-nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgb(28, 143, 124);
}

    /* ul Container*/
.main-nav-list {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 40%;
}

    /* Logo wrapper */
.logo-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 20%;
}

    /* Responsive images */
.main-nav img {
    max-height: 150px;
    max-width: 75px;
}

.main-nav img:hover { 
    transform: scale(1.05); 
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation" class="main-nav">
    <ul class="main-nav-list">
        <li class="fb">
            <a href="#facebook">
                <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/capsocial-round/500/facebook-512.png" alt="">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#yelp">
               <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-media-2169/24/social_media_social_media_logo_yelp-512.png" alt="">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#linkedin">
                <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/linkedin_circle_color-512.png" alt="">
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="logo-wrapper">
        <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/icontober/64/Inkcontober_Deep_Dive_Suit-512.png" alt="" class="logo">
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hey thanks, this works great! I figured that out, but I ended up having to use z-index to enable some hover effects. Is there an easier way to do this so the wrapper div doesn't obstruct the .main-nav-list ?

Comment: Which hover effects on which elements? What do you mean with 'obstruct'?  (PS: i added ```box-sizing: border-box;``` to the ul container so that its padding is not dissturbing the positioning)...

Comment: Could you mean this effect? ```.logo:hover { transform: scale(1.05); }```

Answer (score 1):

Put your nav with certain width in container with body width

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgb(28, 143, 124);
}
.main-nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
    display: flex;
    background-color: rgb(28, 143, 124);
    align-items: center;
    height: auto;
    
}
```

Visit https://codepen.io/losrios1337/pen/mdRmjGL!

Answer (score 0):

Just copy paste this into your given codepen. I guess this is what you needed

```
/* navbar Container */
    .main-nav {
        display: flex;
        background-color: rgb(28, 143, 124);
        align-items: center;
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
    }
    
    /* ul Container*/
    .main-nav 
    .main-nav-list {
        display: flex;
    /*     margin-right: auto;  */
      /* img placement */
        justify-content: flex-end;
        flex-direction: row;
        list-style-type: none;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
    }
    
    /* Responsive images */
    .main-nav 
    .main-nav-list li img {
        display: flex;
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        max-height: 150px;
        max-width: 75px;
    }
    
    /* Logo */
    
    .main-nav .logo {
      display: flex;
      height: auto;
      width: auto;
      max-height: 150px;
      max-width: 75px;
    /*   margin: 0 auto; */
    }
```

[updated codepen](https://codepen.io/hmadhsan/pen/zYNwLXo)

Answer (score -1):

not quite sure what you mean by this "inside the element but outside the element". I guess you mean inside the nav bar but outside of the ul element. If so, then you can add this to your .logo class:

```
position: fixed;
right: 50%;
```

Comment: The logo is inside the <nav> element... But outside of the <ul> element which is inside <nav>. I tried to include the logo as a list item but I wasn't achieving the desired effect. I just wanted to know if this was an okay practice in a professional environment or if I should include it as a list item in the real world.

Comment: Also, that did work, great, thank you. Is this the most practical way of achieving this:?

Comment: if by practical you mean less time consuming and maintenance needed, yes, BUT if your nav bar grows enough, your logo icon will overlap with other icons. In that case you will probably need to start another ul and align it right.

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes but your answer seems to be what I'm looking for. I realized that my text wasn't showing up so it was confusing to read but I fixed it. So if my navbar grows; you mean as in if the ul takes up more space in it's container?

Comment: Also, when using this method, when resizing the window the logo resizes with it. How can I avoid this?

Comment: That happens when using percentages. In this case, we used right: 50%, which makes the position of the object to depend on the width from the right of the parent element. If the parent width becomes shorter, then icon will move with it (or always stay in the middle).

If you want you can also use absolute units (like for example right: 400px; or left: 500em;

Comment: I think you got a downvote because the logo is not exactly centered. The most practical way (often used) to achieve this goal is to wrap the image in a div (see my answer below)...